# Get target file of a shortcut and put that file in a new directory

Tags: windows, powershell, directory

I am trying to get the target files from a folder with many .lnk shortcuts and put them in a new folder using Powershell.  I have the following script and it runs but the output folder does not show anything:

`$WScript = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
Get-ChildItem -Path "<shortcut folder>*.lnk" | ForEach-Object {$WScript.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath} | Out-File -FilePath "<Destination Folder>"`

Comment: What!? Are you asking about .lnk's that lead to executables, .doc/.docx, etc., or the URLthese are pointing to? You can't just copy the URL to a file share. If you are just after files, that that target path is the full UNC to that file and you'd use that UNC to copy from.

Answer (score 1):

Branching off my comment to you. YOu can't Out-File a string, which is what is in the target path. It's not a real file. You can OUt-File that string to a text file if that is what you need, but that does not sound like what you are after.

Just step through each segment to make sure you are getting what you'd expect and use that target in a copy statement.

```
# Validate the lnk data
$WScript = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ClearIEData.lnk" | Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
# Results

    Directory: C:\Users\postanote\Desktop


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name           
----          ------------- ------ ----           
-a----  28-Oct-18     00:52   1293 ClearIEData.lnk
#>

# Extract the lnk target path
$WScript = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ClearIEData.lnk" | 
ForEach-Object {$WScript.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath}
<#
# Results

D:\Tools\ClearIEData.cmd
#>

# Take needed action on the lnk target path info
$WScript = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ClearIEData.lnk" | 
ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item -Path $($WScript.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath) -Destination 'D:\temp' -WhatIf
}
<#
# Results

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Tools\ClearIEData.cmd Destination: D:\temp\ClearIEData.cmd".
#>
```

If satisfied with the results, comment out or remove the -WhatIf and run the code again to take the action.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp' -Filter 'ClearIEData.cmd'
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        05-Mar-20     15:10           2571 ClearIEData.cmd
#>

$WScript = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ClearIEData.lnk" | 
ForEach-Object {
    $WScript.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\LinkFileData.txt' -Append -WhatIf
}
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\LinkFileData.txt'

<#
# Results

D:\Tools\ClearIEData.cmd
#>
```